# Inconsistencies in a famous point group table

Tags: molecular-modeling, mathematical-modeling, symmetry, geometry, structure

## The original resource

"Tables for Group Theory" By Peter Atkins, Mark Child and Courtenay Phillips (1970). I have been using [this 2008 version](http://xuv.scs.illinois.edu/516/handouts/character%20tables_for_group_theory.pdf), in which Pg. 37 has the following table:

[image]

## Some minor inconsistencies

These inconsistencies don't bother me as much as the ones in the next section, but I'm mentioning them because the existence of these inconsistencies could possibly offer a simple explanation for the ones that I describe in the next section (i.e. maybe they simply didn't put much effort into perfecting the diagrams).

- For C<sub>4</sub> one of the lines is black instead of purple
- For C<sub>6</sub> there's extra purple lines which seem to be spurious
- For C<sub>4</sub>, C<sub>5</sub> and C<sub>6</sub> some lines are different sizes when compared to the other lines in the same diagram, or when comparing the diagrams of C<sub>5</sub> and C<sub>5h</sub>.
- If the C<sub>nv</sub> series approaches a cone as n→∞, then the D<sub>nh</sub> series would approach a circle as n→∞, but this is not depicted.

## More uncomfortable inconsistencies

For the inconsistencies that were listed in the previous section, I'm comfortable concluding that the first three were just issues with aesthetics (poor work on the graphics), and that the other inconsistency was simply an oversight.

For the following two, I'm a bit more uncomfortable because they seem much less accidental:

- The purple lines in C<sub>4</sub>-C<sub>6</sub> are perfectly parallel with beige lines, but for C<sub>2</sub> and C<sub>3</sub> they are not. This seems much less accidental than coloring a line black when all other such lines are purple.
- The purple lines in the C<sub>n</sub> and C<sub>nh</sub> series are just thin straight lines, but the D<sub>n</sub> series has ***triangles***. Perhaps in the D<sub>n</sub> series, since there's two different types of appendages (beige and purple), they felt the need to use thicker triangles rather than just thin lines, so that the difference between the two types is made more obvious than it would be if they were just thin lines with different colors (rather than thick triangles with different colors). I'll ask a question about this inconsistency in a separate post, in line with the [one question per post policy](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/421/5).

## Question

Are the C<sub>2</sub> and C<sub>3</sub> diagrams simply in error? For example, is there actually a molecule with a structure like depicted in the C<sub>2</sub> diagram, or is it meant to be just a straight horizontal line with two appendages, like the O-O bond with two H appendages in H2O2, rather than a 3D diamond with two appendages?

Comment: Also it would probably be more correct for the Dnd diagram to converge to two circles on different planes, rather than just one circle!

Answer (score 9):

**After [hours of conversation with three participants including me](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64354393#64354393), I can make the following conclusions.**

## Answer to the question

It's likely an unintentional "error" in the publication.  In the C<sub>2</sub> and C<sub>3</sub> figures, the purple lines can indeed be aligned with the beige lines, as in the diagrams for C<sub>4</sub>, C<sub>5</sub>, C<sub>6</sub>, C<sub>2h</sub>, C<sub>3h</sub>, C<sub>4h</sub>, C<sub>5h</sub>, C<sub>6h</sub>. The authors likely did not intend to draw the purple lines with non-zero angles with respect to the beige lines, especially in the case of the C<sub>3</sub> diagram, which seems to be unintentionally divergent from the C<sub>3h</sub> diagram (although they may have had specific molecules in mind when choosing the diagrams for C<sub>2</sub> and C<sub>3</sub>).

## Further conclusions

It is not technically incorrect for the angles between the purple lines and the beige lines to be non-zero in C<sub>2</sub> and C<sub>3</sub> molecules (as long as the angles are not chosen in such a way to promote the point groups to a higher one, like D<sub>3h</sub> in the case of C<sub>3</sub>), but if drawn that way, it would have been more consistent for the angles to be non-zero in the C<sub>4</sub>, C<sub>5</sub> and C<sub>6</sub> cases as well.

Also, the diagram for C<sub>2</sub> is indeed a valid structure with that point group, but it may not be as easy to find a real-world molecule that has that shape, compared to the H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub> example that I suggested in the question post. The diagram for C<sub>2v</sub> is essentially the one in the top-right corner of the screenshot below from the Landolt-Boernstein series, so it's a pyramid whose 2D diagram looks like a diamond:

[image]

By adding one atom along the H-Si line, and another identical atom in the H-Si line directly opposite to the first H-Si line, we can maintain the  C<sub>2</sub> axis while breaking the vertical planes, therefore demoting the point group from C<sub>2v</sub> to C<sub>2</sub>. The new atoms that are added along the H-Si lines could be added in between the H and Si atoms, or outside of the original pyramid, as in the diagram in the original question post: in both cases we would get a C<sub>2</sub> molecule, but in both cases it's harder to find a real molecule that would have this shape, compared to the ease with which we found H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub> as a simpler example of a C<sub>2</sub> molecule. Likewise, H<sub>2</sub>O would have been a more obvious choice for the C<sub>2v</sub> example, compared to the above (non-standard) isomer of H<sub>2</sub>Si<sub>2</sub>.